# Queryset in ModelForm is properly limited initially, but not when form is submitted with errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.3

I want to limit a queryset for a form based on the user sending the request.  I am having some trouble getting a ModelForm to properly limit the queryset of a field when the form is submitted but invalid.  The form gets redisplayed with the error text, but no longer has the queryset limited.  What could be the cause here?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Prescription(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
```

**views.py**

```
import medical.models as models
import medical.forms as forms
from django.shortcuts import render

def add_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PrescriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = forms.make_prescription_form(request.user)
    return render(request, 'add_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
import medical.models as models
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField

class PrescriptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Prescription

def make_prescription_form(dr):
    class PrescriptionForm(ModelForm):
        patient = ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Patient.objects.filter(doctor=dr))
        class Meta:
            model = models.Prescription
    return PrescriptionForm
```

**add_form.html**

```
{{ request.user.first_name }}
{% if form.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this, or suggestion on a better way to achieve the same thing!  Let me know if any more files would be helpful.  I'm using Django 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it looks like you left off a bit - `make_prescription_form` returns a class, not a form instance, and you're passing the class directly to the rendering in the GET path.  I am assuming that's a typo.

You're not using your `make_prescription_form` wrapper in the POST path.  The smallest change from this implementation would be:

```
def add_form(request):
    form_class = forms.make_prescription_form(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = form_class()
    return render(request, 'add_form.html', {'form': form})
```

As for other ways to do this - you can just set the form field's queryset directly in your view.

```
forms.py
class PrescriptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Prescription

views.py
def add_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrescriptionForm(request.POST)
        form.fields['patient'].queryset = models.Patient.objects.filter(doctor=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PrescriptionForm()
        form.fields['patient'].queryset = models.Patient.objects.filter(doctor=request.user)
    return render(request, 'add_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Or set `doctor` as an argument to PrescriptionForm's `__init__` and update the queryset there:

```
forms.py
class PrescriptionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Prescription

    def __init__(self, *args, doctor=None, **kwargs):
        super(PrescriptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.doctor is not None:
            self.fields['patient'] = models.Patient.objects.filter(doctor=doctor)

views.py
def add_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrescriptionForm(request.POST, doctor=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PrescriptionForm(doctor=request.user)
    return render(request, 'add_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Additionally, I wanted it to return a form class.  I am using this same view to edit/add multiple types of objects.  So I have a section where it loads the proper class into a variable, then uses that variable for the rest of the function.